# appendString from array to array in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, append

I have 2 independent Plist NSMutableArrays containing strings.

1st array example contains the below products:

football,
badminton racket,
tennis ball,

2nd array contains the quantities of the above products:

12,
5,
17,

What I want to achieve is add the quantities to the end of the product names i.e like the below:

football QTY: (12),
badminton racket QTY: (5),
tennis ball QTY: (17),

NSMutableString *emailString = [NSMutableString string];

```
for(int i = 0; i < [theProducts count]; i++) {

    NSString *str = [theProducts objectAtIndex:i];
    [emailString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<br /> %@: QTY: %@", str, theQuantity]];
}
```

Any recommendations for the best way to do this would be most appreciated. I've looked at append string methods and looping over to add the string to the string in the above arrays however I can't seem to get this to work :-(

Thanks for looking!

UPDATE:

This works for me

```
   NSMutableString *emailString = [NSMutableString string];

for(int i = 0; i < [theProducts count]; i++) {

     NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<br /> %@ QTY: (%d)", [theProducts objectAtIndex: i], [[theQuantity objectAtIndex: i] intValue], nil];
    [emailString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result]];

}
```

Comment: Hi Kai sorry i forgot to add the code silly me. Any way here you go. 
theProducts and theQuantity are the 2 NSMutableArrays what this produces is the product name with the whole quantity array added to the end i.e. football QTY: (12, 5, 17) and i need it to break the quantities up at the index so football is 12 so on and so on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but I'd probably use something like this:

```
   NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ QTY: (%d)", name, quantity, nil];
```

You would substitute your string array for name, and grab the quantity from the second array in whatever way makes sense. If the first array is called names, and the second is an array of NSNumber objects called quantities, the line might look like this:

```
   NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ QTY: (%d)", [names objectAtIndex: i], [[quantities objectAtIndex: i] intValue], nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it (untested code, straight out of my mind):

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int i = 0;

for (NSString *what in itemArray) {
    [newAray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: (%d)", what, [quantityArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
    i++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be that hard... Code out of my mind. So there could be errors ;).

```
int i = 0;
int len = products.count;

for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ QTY: (%d)", [products objectAtIndex:i], ([quantities objectAtIndex:i]]
}
```

*Note: You have to check, that both arrays have the same count. So best would be to also insert an assert in the front to check that condition..*